# How to unescape HTML Tags in string java

Tags: java, html, regex, string

I want to content in pure string format from HTML String.

My original string is like this:

```
1. <br/>Test Plan: YTL Test Plan for Release 1<br/><br/>Test Case: Clarity TC - Provisioning 1<br/><br/>Test Script: to test provisioning ADD option<br/><br/>Project Area: CLM Test (Quality Management)
2. Failing Test Case &quot;Clarity TC - Provisioning 1&quot;
```

Now, I want to replace all html characters and have it in string format.

Currently I am using **StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(String)** to resolve my purpose and it is giving me output as below

```
1. <br/>Test Plan: YTL Test Plan for Release 1<br/><br/>Test Case: Clarity TC - Provisioning 1<br/><br/>Test Script: to test provisioning ADD option<br/><br/>Project Area: CLM Test (Quality Management)
2. Failing Test Case "Clarity TC - Provisioning 1"
```

So it is working for my second string but not for first one

Can we achieve this with help of some class?

I don't want to use regex or replace methods instead is there any other class to do needful?

Comment: you could try `String#replace()` for `<br/>`

Comment: Do you want to remove the HTML tags in the first string?

Comment: Both the strings and i dont want to use replace method

Comment: What is it you want? You're saying that `unescapeHtml` works for you, then say you want to achieve this with a class. `StringEscapeUtils` is a class that does it. Show what result you want.

Comment: StringEscapeUtils  works for second string and not for first one as the first string still contains `<br/>`

Answer (score 0):

1) Use the [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) class:-

```
public static String html2String(String html) {
    return Jsoup.parse(html).text();
 }
```

2) Using Regex you can do something like this:-

```
String str="<br/>Test Plan: YTL Test Plan for Release 1<br/><br/>Test Case: Clarity TC - Provisioning 1<br/><br/>Test Script: to test provisioning ADD option<br/><br/>Project Area: CLM Test (Quality Management)";
  String rx="\\<[^>]*>";
  System.out.println(str.replaceAll(rx, ""));
```

3) Using com.google.gdata.util.common.html.[HtmlToText](http://www.udel.edu/CIS/software/dist/google/calendar/java.client/gdata/java/src/com/google/gdata/util/common/html/HtmlToText.java) like below:-

```
  HtmlToText.htmlToPlainText(string)
```

Comment: I will tryout Jsoup and then will confirm

Answer (score 0):

I'm faced with the same problem as you.
And instead of using br tags for new lines I used '\n' and to keep text formatted I added this styles to an element where this text is showed:

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
```